# Joining multiple tables which satisfies multiple columns in both the tables

Tags: java, sql, database, join

I want to get the data from two tables which has one similar column.

```
Table A

x   y   z  a  b  

1   48 36  d5 8d  
2   78  36 2t 15
3   99  54  s5  14
4   48  73  58  11



Table B

x   y   z  a  b  

1   48 95  d9 69  
2   98  36 3c vv
3   93  39  df  1bb
4   48  73  58  11
```

I want to get the `y,z,b` values from the table when column `y=48,z=73,a=58,b=11`.
I used the `join query` like this but its not working.

```
Select x,y,z,a,b from A join B in A.y=B.y=48 and A.z=B.z=73 and A.a=B.a=58 and A.b=B.b=11;
```

Can you give me the right solution

Comment: Join ON, not IN, is the correct syntax! And only two values for =.

Comment: `and A.z=B.z=73` is totally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joins are defined through the `ON` keyword not using `IN`. You are also mixing the join condition and the filter condition. `a=b=x` doesn't work in SQL.

You will also need to fully qualify the columns in your select list, otherwise you'll get an error that the column name is ambiguous.

```
Select a.x, a.y, a.z, a.a, a.b 
from A 
  join B on A.y=B.y 
        and A.z=B.z 
        and A.a=B.a 
        and A.b=B.b
where a.y = 48
  and a.z = 73
  and a.a = 58
  and a.b = 11
```

Your comment "*which has one similar column*" seems to indicate that the join should in fact only be done through the column `x` not based on all columns you want to filter on:

So you might actually want:

```
Select a.x, a.y, a.z, a.a, a.b 
from A 
  join B on a.x = b.x -- only use `x` for the join condition
where a.y = 48
  and a.z = 73
  and a.a = 58
  and a.b = 11
```

Answer (score -1):

try below

```
SELECT
    A.X,
    B.Y,
    A.Z,
    A.A,
    A.B
FROM
    A,
    B
WHERE A.Y=B.Y AND A.Y=48
AND A.Z=B.Z AND A.Z=73
AND A.A=B.A AND A.A=58
AND A.B=B.B AND A.B=11;
```

Comment: You should really get used to explicit `JOIN` operators in the `FROM` clause instead of the outdated implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause